# How do I check my public facing remote node is up and running via a web browser?

Tags: monerod, vps, server

I have a Monero daemon (monerod) setup on a public facing VPS server. How can I check it's running fine by using a web browser, or what type of linux command can I run?

I'm using the default ports.

Comment: mine shows http://xxxxxx.com:18088/get_info x1q -- seems good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily test via the daemon RPC interface. Assuming default ports used, you can browse to:

```
http://x.x.x.x:18081/get_info
```

Replacing `x.x.x.x` with your servers IP address. This will return some JSON like follows if the node is up and there are no firewalls blocking it:

```
{
  "alt_blocks_count": 0,
  "block_size_limit": 600000,
  "block_size_median": 85,
  "block_weight_limit": 600000,
  "block_weight_median": 85,
  "bootstrap_daemon_address": "",
  "cumulative_difficulty": 49806683508,
  "database_size": 2565951488,
  "difficulty": 68748,
  "free_space": 92892508160,
  "grey_peerlist_size": 373,
  "height": 1138572,
  "height_without_bootstrap": 1138572,
  "incoming_connections_count": 0,
  "mainnet": false,
  "nettype": "testnet",
  "offline": false,
  "outgoing_connections_count": 8,
  "rpc_connections_count": 1,
  "stagenet": false,
  "start_time": 1548297116,
  "status": "OK",
  "target": 120,
  "target_height": 0,
  "testnet": true,
  "top_block_hash": "398f1733354f8371440d9ecb9947e69f7a615353f32c630b220083bb674192af",
  "tx_count": 57606,
  "tx_pool_size": 1,
  "untrusted": false,
  "update_available": false,
  "version": "0.13.0.0-master",
  "was_bootstrap_ever_used": false,
  "white_peerlist_size": 43
}
```

Comment: whats a sample public node one can query to test this out?

Comment: http://node.supportxmr.com:18081/get_info